# Adding public pages to a .Net 4.7.2 Visual Basic code having Azure Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, azure, azure-authentication

I'm assigned to add Azure Auth to an existing .NET Framework 4.7.2 Visual Basic (sigh) code.

So I created an empty project and configured all Azure connections and up to this point it works fine.

Now I'm stuck adding public pages to this project, because all pages redirect to Microsoft login page by default.

How can I add one or more public pages (eg. Home.aspx, Contact.aspx, v.s.)?

My startup code is below. If you need more, ask me which one and I can add.

`App_Start/StartupAuth.vb`

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin

Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance"))
    Private Shared tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:TenantId")
    Private Shared postLogoutRedirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri")
    Private Shared authority As String = aadInstance & tenantId

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .Authority = authority,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
              .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                          Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                      End Function
              }
        })
        ' This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function EnsureTrailingSlash(ByRef value As String) As String
        If (IsNothing(value)) Then
            value = String.Empty
        End If

        If (Not value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal)) Then
            Return value & "/"
        End If

        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Files in the project

[image]

`web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880

  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ca2f05b770b1" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="xxx.xxx.xx" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="9696b0a8-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44308/" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings` file ?

Comment: @Harshitha WebForms projects don't have an appsettings file, they have `web.config` instead.

Comment: There is no appsettings file. I edited the question and listed all the files I have.

Comment: Yes, `web.config` file, I meant the settings you have done for your app.

Comment: You say it's an existing project, but that file list looks almost exactly like a new project created from the stock ASP.NET project template (only the `Account` directory, `Ergec.aspx` and `ViewSwitcher.ascx` are non-default).

Comment: @Harshitha I added web.config.

Comment: @Dai I'm testing on a fresh project to make sure it works. Then I'll add it to existing one.

Comment: In `Web.config`, Change `location path` to `Account.aspx` and check once.

Comment: @Harshitha yes and no. adding aspx doesn't work but I added `Index.aspx` under `Account` and `/Account/Index` worked as public. Also created a dummy folder and put `Dummy.aspx` under it and `/DummyFolder/Dummy` worked too. Thanks a lot. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configurations which you have done in `Web.config` file to allow the users to access public pages is correct excluding the Azure Authentication.

- But you have missed the `.aspx` and `foldername` in the location path.
- If you want to access the page which is at the root of the Application, then the location path has to be

```
  <location path="PageName.aspx">
```

- Based on your folder structure, if you want to give access to  `Default.aspx`, then the location path must be

```
  <location path="Default.aspx">
```

- If you want to provide access to the page which is in the folder, then it has to be

```
   <location path="Accounts/Account.aspx">
```

[image]